# "Ping" a tensorflow serving server

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

I implemented several gRPC services, which all share the basic interface which allows me to "ping" them to see if they are up. For that, I have the getServiceVersion() request, which returns me the service version if the service is up, and the request breaks if the service is not up. How would you do this is tf serving? Or is there a better procedure in GRPC in general?

If no other answer comes up, I will just create a ping model which returns the service version from a constant. This would be a prediction model which predicts with 100% accuracy if the predictor is up. :)

Comment: Can you take a look at this [TensorFlow Serving Model Status Probe](https://github.com/codycollier/tfs-model-status-probe) or this [link](https://github.com/helmut-hoffer-von-ankershoffen/jetson/blob/master/workflow/deploy/tensorflow-serving/src/webservice/health/healthz.py). There's a [similar issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/671) from TF serving repo which can give you few more workarounds for your question. Thanks!